# How do I forward fisrt n calls to one phone number and then next n calls to another phone number in sip voip?

Tags: sip, voip, forwarding, sip-server, python-sip

I have a vonage business account in which I receive hundreds of calls per minute. I want to outsource my process to different organizations so that they can handle those calls. In this I want to make a system in which make list of phone numbers of organization and number of phone calls they can handle amd forward those calls to each of. them list wise.
Example-

[image]

In the above image is this list of all numbers which should receive the call first.
The first 10 calls should be forwarded to first number.
The next 7 calls should be forwarded to second number.
The next 12 calls should be forwarded to third numbers.
and so on...